# Micrometer percentile value not available

Tags: prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I have a timer bean created like this to register the latency of the downstream calls performed in parallel in separate thread pool executor.

```
@Bean
Timer apiLatencyTimer() {
    return Timer.builder("all_apis_warmup_timer")
        .distributionStatisticExpiry(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
        .description("Latency timer for all endpoints")
        .publishPercentileHistogram(true)
        .publishPercentiles(0.95d, 0.99d)
        .register(Metrics.globalRegistry);
}
```

and I register the time like below in the thread calling the downstream service

```
private void tryWarmupEndpoint() {
    Timer.Sample timerSample = Timer.start();
    try {
        warmupEndpoint(); // Here is where I call the downstream endpoints
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("Error during warmup of endpoint \[{}\]", getEndpoint(), e);
    } finally {
        timerSample.stop(timer);
    }
}
```

I have this deployed in K8 environment and I notice the percentile values are available in some of the pods and NOT AVAILABLE in few of the pods.

When accessing the percentile values like this: `apiLatencyTimer.takeSnapshot().percentileValues()` I see the array is empty in some of the pods.

I am expecting the percentileValues are available in all the pods. I verified that all the pods do call the downstream services and there are enough calls performed to collect the percentile metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use the global registry but let Spring inject `MeterRegistry` to your components. You should not create a `@Bean` for `Timer`s either but use its builder, please check the docs first.

The separator in Micrometer is `.` please use that and it will convert to `_` in case of Prometheus.

If you use `publishPercentileHistogram` you don't need `publishPercentiles` since you can calculate whatever percentiles you want on your metrics backend (Prometheus).